# How to write a Long paragraph in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**How to write a Long paragraph in node.js?**

I'm using this way But is very difficult to edit

```
bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Line1\n Line2\n Line3\n Line4\n', opts);
```

Is There an Easy way to use the paragraph?

Comment: You mean a way to split the string in the code when there is a newline? Just concatenate a bunch of strings, each ending on `\n`.

Comment: I mean, Just Copy and paste the pharagraph or with newline, when i entered to new line I got error

Comment: If you want to use copy-paste, then I think you should use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**
With node >= 4, you can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that could span multiple lines preserving newline character.

```
console.log(
 `Line 1
  Line 2
  Line 3`
);
```

**Option 2:**
You can also `join` multiple string stored as array.

```
[
 'line 1',
 'line 2',
 'line 3'
].join('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you I Changed `'` to ` ` `

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use es6 [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this:

```
let str = `
    Line1
    Line2
    Line3`;

bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, str, opts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
let longMessage = `Line1
    Line2
    Line3
    Line4
    `;
bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, longMessage, opts);
```